# PDFKit rendering blank map instead a Leaflet Map

Tags: javascript, django, leaflet, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I want to download a PDF from a Django view. To do that, I have a function that is triggered by a link. The PDF will contain a Leaflet Map. This map has markers, polyline and circle.

I'm using `PDFKit` and `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5 (with patched qt)`.

The problem is that it isn't rendering. It just show "+", "-", "Leaflet" and all the rest is blank.

I've already tried some alternatives:

[Approach: python-pdfkit convert webpage(JS generated) into PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757503/approach-python-pdfkit-convert-webpagejs-generated-into-pdf)

[wkhtmltopdf and leaflet wait for map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251458/wkhtmltopdf-and-leaflet-wait-for-map)

https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1648

Neither of them worked. The `iframe` I thought would have some solution, but it didn't render. The `javascript-delay` alternative, didn't work too.

My view:

```
def download_PDF(request):

    latlongs = request.session['latlongs']
    latitudeIni = float(request.session['latitudeIni'])
    longIni = request.session['longIni']

    option = {
        'dpi': 300,
        'image-dpi': 400,
        'zoom': 0.7,
        'window-status': 'maploaded',
        'javascript-delay' : '30000'        
    }

    argumento = {'latlongs' : latlongs,
        'latitudeIni' : latitudeIni,
        'longIni' : longIni}

    template = get_template('pdf_template/pdf_localizacao.html')

    html = template.render(argumento)  
    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html, False, options=option)

    response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="home_page.pdf"'

    return response
```

My html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

... JS links...


<style>
...
.my-map{
        width: 800px;
        height: 600px;
        }
        /* .my-map div {
        transform: none !important;
        } */
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- <iframe width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"> -->
    <div id='map' class="my-map"></div>
    <!-- </iframe> -->
...
<script>
        var BING_KEY = 'AuhiCJHlGzhg93IqUH_oCpl_-ZUrIE6SPftlyGYUvr9Amx5nzA-WqGcPquyFZl4L'        
        var canvas = L.canvas();
        var map = L.map('map', {renderer : canvas}).setView({{ latlongs.0 }},15);
        var bingLayer = L.tileLayer.bing(BING_KEY).addTo(map);

        var orangeIcon = new L.Icon({
            iconUrl: '/image/marker-icon-2x-orange.png',
            shadowUrl: '/image/marker-shadow.png',
            iconSize: [25, 41],
            iconAnchor: [12, 41],
            popupAnchor: [1, -34],
            shadowSize: [41, 41]
        });

        var circle = L.circle([{{ latitudeIni|safe }}, {{ longIni|safe }}], {
            color: 'yellow',
            fillColor: '#eff178',
            fillOpacity: 0.5,        
            radius: 1,
            renderer : canvas
        }).addTo(map);

        var marker = L.marker({{ latlongs.0 }}).addTo(map);
        marker.bindPopup("<b>Início do Duto</b><br>[Latitude,Longitude] = {{ latlongs.0 }}").openPopup();

        var marker = L.marker({{ latlongs|last }}).addTo(map);
        marker.bindPopup("<b>Final do Duto</b><br>[Latitude,Longitude] = {{ latlongs|last }}").openPopup();   

        var popup = L.popup();

        var printer = L.easyPrint({
                tileLayer: bingLayer,
                sizeModes: ['Current', 'A4Landscape', 'A4Portrait'],
                filename: 'myMap',
                exportOnly: true,
                hideControlContainer: true
            }).addTo(map);  

        var latlngs = {{ latlongs }};
        var polyline = L.polyline(latlngs, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);


    </script>
</body>
```

The `wkhtmltopdf` don't give any error, or warning about the JS of the leaflet and its CSS.

I've tried many combinations of the links above and also from other sites.

Can anyone figure out the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and got it working in the end, but I found it very temperamental and had to significantly simplify my HTML/JS code.

- Set `L_NO_TOUCH = true;` and `L_DISABLE_3D = true;`
- Remove all instances of `bindTooltip` (in your case, `bindPopup`?)
- For others searching, though not applicable to your case, I also had to remove the `<meta name="viewport" />` tag, and any width or height settings on `body` and `html`.

Comment: Thanks man, I've already give up this issue and started another part of the code. Thanks for your time, in the future if I return to this issue I will inform you!